# cUrl --user authentication with Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, api, curl

I need to auth on server side with user credentials for every request of sensitive data (it will be replaced to oAuth in the future).

With cUrl request looks like:

```
curl -u username:p@ssw0rD http://api_url
```

How It can be implemented with Angular JS.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement Basic auth with Angular JS is to encrypt you credentials in Base 64 and pass it in Authorization header.

```
$http ({
        method: 'ANY',
        url: 'some url'
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Base64.encode(login+':'+password)
        },
      })

App.factory ('Base64', function () {
  /* jshint ignore:start */

  var keyStr = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';

  return {
    encode: function (input) {
      var output = "";
      var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
      var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
      var i = 0;

      do {
        chr1 = input.charCodeAt (i++);
        chr2 = input.charCodeAt (i++);
        chr3 = input.charCodeAt (i++);

        enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
        enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
        enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
        enc4 = chr3 & 63;

        if (isNaN (chr2)) {
          enc3 = enc4 = 64;
        } else if (isNaN (chr3)) {
          enc4 = 64;
        }

        output = output +
        keyStr.charAt (enc1) +
        keyStr.charAt (enc2) +
        keyStr.charAt (enc3) +
        keyStr.charAt (enc4);
        chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
        enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";
      } while (i < input.length);

      return output;
    },

    decode: function (input) {
      var output = "";
      var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
      var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
      var i = 0;

      // remove all characters that are not A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +, /, or =
      var base64test = /[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g;
      if (base64test.exec (input)) {
        window.alert ("There were invalid base64 characters in the input text.\n" +
        "Valid base64 characters are A-Z, a-z, 0-9, '+', '/',and '='\n" +
        "Expect errors in decoding.");
      }
      input = input.replace (/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

      do {
        enc1 = keyStr.indexOf (input.charAt (i++));
        enc2 = keyStr.indexOf (input.charAt (i++));
        enc3 = keyStr.indexOf (input.charAt (i++));
        enc4 = keyStr.indexOf (input.charAt (i++));

        chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
        chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
        chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

        output = output + String.fromCharCode (chr1);

        if (enc3 != 64) {
          output = output + String.fromCharCode (chr2);
        }
        if (enc4 != 64) {
          output = output + String.fromCharCode (chr3);
        }

        chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
        enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";

      } while (i < input.length);

      return output;
    }
  };

  /* jshint ignore:end */
});
```